# Can you override private virtual methods?

Tags: c#, virtual

I think you can and my colleage thinks you cannot!

Comment: What about just trying? Every Windows system nowadays has a C# compiler ...

Comment: **Related:** [Why are private virtual methods illegal in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3082310/1497596)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't even *declare* private virtual methods. The only time it would make any sense at all would be if you had:

```
public class Outer
{
    private virtual void Foo() {}

    public class Nested : Outer
    {
        private override void Foo() {}
    }
}
```

... that's the only scenario in which a type has access to its parent's private members. However, this is still prohibited:

> Test.cs(7,31): error CS0621:
>   'Outer.Nested.Foo()': virtual or
>   abstract members cannot be private
>   Test.cs(3,26): error CS0621:
>   'Outer.Foo()': virtual or abstract
>   members cannot
>           be private

Comment: Another time it would make sense would be if a derived class could override a private virtual method in the base, and if that method (and that method alone) could call the base-class implementation.  This would allow a base class to enforce a requirement that all calls to a particular base-class function must be bracketed by some code in the base class (e.g. if Dispose(Boolean) were private virtual, a non-virtual base-class Dispose could do an Interlocked.Exchange() to ensure Dispose(Boolean) was only called once.

Answer (score 5):

Your colleague is right. You can't declare private virtual methods because there's no point (since there'd be no way to override them)...

But you can override protected virtual methods.

Comment: Sure you could override them; see Jon's example.

Comment: But even in Jon's example, the compiler won't allow it.

Comment: My point is simply that your claim that "there would be no way to override them" is incorrect. There would be a way to override them. The reason private virtual methods are illegal is because the language design committee doesn't like them, not because they are logically inconsistent.

Comment: Ah...that makes sense. I see what you'te saying and totally agree.

Comment: Excuse me, but there's a LOT of point to private virtual methods; a derived class overriding base behaviour is one thing, a derived class CALLING a base method is another thing entirely. It is very much desirable to not have child-class implementers have the ability to mess up the call orders of critically-ordered methods, even if they are overridable.

Answer (score 0):

You won't fund your private method in your derivative class. So the virtual keyword has no sens in this case.