# Does private mean different things in C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, language-design, private

I was wondering why C# doesn't allow `private virtual` functions and ran across the aptly named [Why are private virtual methods illegal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082310/why-are-private-virtual-methods-illegal-in-c)

In the accepted answer [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert) (who probably knows what he's talking about...) said:

> If you desire to restrict the ability to override the method in non-nested derived classes then you can do so by restricting the ability of non-nested classes to derive from the base class;

In C++ `private: virtual` makes sense because it means *"I want classes derived from me to override the functionality of this function but they shouldn't be able to call it directly"*, in other words `private` controls who can call a function and has no effect on who can override it.

I realize that since only derived classes can override in the first place and since C# prohibits `private virtual` functions this question may be meaningless, are there other scenarios in which the protection level of a function can effect who can override it (`protected internal` perhaps)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want the C++ world of being able to override but not call; then no: you can't do that in C#. The *other way around* is fine, though - either don't mark it `virtual` in the first place, or mark it `sealed` if it is *already* `virtual`.