# Error: can't declare a virtual/ abstract member private

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are private virtual methods illegal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082310/why-are-private-virtual-methods-illegal-in-c)

I have the following code in C#, and Visual Studio is complaining in the Derived class that i cant declare a virtual/ abstract member private.. but i am not .. so does anyone have some ideas? Thanks

```
public class  Base
{
    private const string Name= "Name1";
    protected virtual string Member1
    {
    get{
       return Name;
       }
     }
}

public class Derived: Base
{
 private const string Name= "Name2";
 protected override string Member1
 {
  get{
     return Name;
     }
 }   
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message too? In full?

Comment: that's not at all correct C#... Please post your actual code!

Comment: I hope your actual code has `class` in lowercase and member functions are properly declared like `protected virtual string Member1();`?

Comment: this is not a duplicate of the other post. The members are declared as protected, not private. And yes, i have already edited the code.

Comment: @Rosie, this version of your code compiles. Are you sure the problem is not in a different area? Provide a snippet that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. yes, you are right, it did compile fine. It somehow was giving me this warning before I compiled it.. very weird of Visual Studio..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unable to reproduce, having fixed the case of "Class" and provided method bodies:

```
class Base
{    
    protected virtual string Member1() { return null; }    
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override string Member1() { return null; }   
}
```

This compiles with no warnings.

If you were trying to declare *fields* as virtual, you'd get:

> Test.cs(11,30): error CS0106: The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item
>   Test.cs(17,31): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item

Comment: Done same with props - no problem either...

Comment: Thanks, Jon. It did compile fine. Visual studio is weird, it kept on giving me this warning, until I compiled it...

Answer (score 2):

virtual method has to have a body:

```
public class  Base
{

    protected virtual string Member1()
    {
        return "";
    }

}

public class Derived: Base
{
    protected override string Member1()
    {
        return "this is the ovveride";
    }

}
```